# Azure DevOps: How to set a Pipeline Variable on a Release?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to create a simple Release Pipeline that:

1. sets a **value** via a script
2. asks a user to manually check the value, and modify it if needed
3. goes on with the pipeline, using the value

What is the easiest way to achieve this functionality in Azure DevOps?

---

I have tried to define a [Pipeline Variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcBqn.png) called TestVariable, with initial value of 1, where I will store the **value**.
A Pipeline Variable seems a good option to me, because its value can be easily modified by the user, during manual check.

The problem is, I cannot set its value via a script (as per point 1. above).
I have tried to set its value to 2 via a [Bash Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5pxw.png), but it does not work as you can [see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AsOm.png).
Here is the code, if you want to try yourself:

```
echo $(TestVariable)
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=TestVariable;]2"
echo $(TestVariable)
```

I searched thoroughly the Azure documentation but I could not find any solution. Is there any way to set a Pipeline Variable through a script, or to achieve the 3 above mentioned points with another strategy?

Answer (score 0):

The method you used to update the value is correct.

Refer to this doc: [Set variables in scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts)

> A script in your pipeline can define a variable so that it can be consumed by one of the subsequent steps in the pipeline.

It will not work on the current task,  but the updated value can be used in the next tasks.

Here is an example:

```
steps:

- bash: |
   echo $(TestVariable)
   echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=TestVariable;]2"
   
  displayName: 'Bash Script'

- bash: |
   echo $(TestVariable)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer Kevin. The problem is, I would like to set a variable in a place that can be easily accessed by the user (like in the Pipeline Variables screenshot I showed). Do you know any good option?

Comment: In Release Pipeline, I think the Pipeline variable is the easiest way for other users to access. Then can access the Release Pipeline variable when running the Release Pipeline or Edit the Release Pipeline.

Comment: Another method is Variable Group. You can set the variables in Library -> Variable Groups. Then you can use the variable group in Release Pipeline. User can access the variable via going to Library -> Variable group.

Comment: Well, the problem with both these method is you can not edit the variable via script.
I need a method where the variable can be edited both via the script and by the user.

Comment: can you explain your requirement in details? then I can do more investigation . For the script, we can use set variable command to update it and for the users, we can manually edit it.

Comment: Thank you Kevin. I just need to create a Release Pipeline that sets a value, asks the user to check it and modify it if needed, and then goes on with the pipeline. It seems to be super simple, but I'm still struggling with it.

Comment: From your requirement, I think it will be enough if you only use Pipeline variables. Then you can use  the variable via the format $(variablename).

Comment: If I add I Pipeline Variable in the menu I screenshot, the user can modify it, but it cannot be modified via script, as I explained at the beginning.

Comment: For this question, you can refer to my answer. You method is correct. But the updated value needs to be used in the next tasks.

Comment: I am sorry, maybe I am not explaining clearly enough. FIRST the value needs to be modified by the script. THEN it needs to be modified by the user.
With your method, the variable is correctly modified by the script, that's true. But THEN, it cannot be modified by the user. To be precise, the user does not see the modified value after the first task. He only sees the original value.